# Ews Managed APi always returning Success for every item in DeleteItems?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

When trying to implement Bulk delete i found a strange behavior in EWS managed APi, it seems that DeleteItems always returns me success even if it fails (mail not deleted) or if ItemId doesn't exist.

Any idea why ?

Comment: You get success for the `OverallResult` in `ServiceResponseCollection`, or for every item in it?

Comment: sadly, both, for ServiceResponse and for every item in the ServiceResponseCollection.